# adjustable Button size in UI5

Tags: button, sapui5

I have a button on the Master Page of a "Flexible Column Layout" : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout

which contains a button (having long text) on the titleAction of the Master(semantic) page.

However, when I click on the master items and open the details page, the buttons shrinks and shows only half of the text.

Could anyone help on how to fix this ?

I would like the complete Button text to be seen even after the page is shrunk to half.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for me the explored [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.7/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.OverflowToolbarSimple/preview) is working fine

```
<m:Button text="Never" >
<m:layoutData>
    <m:OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow"/>
</m:layoutData>
```

Comment: this does not work. I also referred a similar example on the demo kit but same issue.

Comment: @Nandan could you provide the xml part or control code to have a better idea?